# Tying multiselect into database query in laravel with vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Currently, in Laravel, I have a working Vue instance of multiselect, which successfully displays options that are hard coded but also allows me to save the input as a tag if an option doesn't exist:

```
new Vue({
    components: {
        Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
    },
    data () {
        return {
            value: [],
            options: [
              { tag: '123', name: 'Test 1'},
              { tag: '456', name: 'Test 2'},


            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addTag (newTag) {
          const tag = {
            name: newTag,
            code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
          }
          this.options.push(tag)
          this.value.push(tag)
        }
    }
}).$mount('#tagContent');
```

I'm trying to tie this into a database query in my controller to get an autocomplete functionality from database results. I have the function and I've tested it by hard-coding `$s` but I now have it set to get input with a  name of tagSearch and I'm very confused on how to tie this in so that the search on my multiselect will hit this function properly. I'm new to Vue so any help here is much appreciated

```
public function searchTags()
{   
    $s = "%" . Input::get('tagSearch') . "%";
    $search = Tags::where('TAG_DATA', 'LIKE', $s)->get();

    return json_encode($search);
}
```

Comment: You make a route in Laravel first?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes I have a route to the controller

Comment: So, you can make a HTTP request from your vue frontend to this route and get the details in JSON.

Comment: How do I do that through the vue component though? I just need to figure out how to send the multiselect as INPUT value into this function and return them as options

Comment: Well, not a Vue expert but I would use javascript's [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). You can use that or can use `axios` as mentioned in [this doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html).